# How to execute ping command in Android with interface name (example: wlan0)?

Tags: android, linux

I am developing one android app where i need to use ping command with interface name .Ping command without interface is working fine but if i specify the interface name ping does not work.Ping with interface name works in linux terminal without root permission.

I am trying below command

```
pingCommand = "ping -I wlan0 192.168.230.2"; //Does not work
proc = runtime.exec(pingCommand);

pingCommand = "ping 192.168.230.2"; //This does work
proc = runtime.exec(pingCommand);
```

Please share some solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiment regarding ping using interface in Android and i have below conclusions.

1) ROOT permission is required to do Ping using specific interface (Ex: wlan0).
But one specified phone "**HUAWEI NXT-AL 10(Android 6.0)**" ,where i am able to use interface (wlan0) for ping without ROOT permission.

2) For other phones (Tried with Moto G, Micoromax android one) if root is enabled then ping is allowed with interface otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the error message that you get, Following is the sample code which works on ubuntu:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RuntimeDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s;
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.119");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println("line: " + s);
            p.waitFor();
            System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
            p.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: I am executing this ping command in Android through program. 
Actually there is no error ,It's like if you give wrong argument/ some arguments which can be run only in super user mode.
As your program runs (ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.119) in Ubuntu directly so it works.

Comment: To get  error ,i have used getErrorStream() instead of getInputStream().
ERROR: ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE: Operation not permitted
Is this mean, root permission is required to use interface for pinging in Android?But in Linux root permission is not required to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Android the command is
"/system/bin/ping my_url_or_ip" this is why you can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

[icmp4a library](https://github.com/marsounjan/icmp4a) for Android is my library that will let you do ICMP ping on specific interface.

You just need to get the [android.net.Network](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network) instance from `ConnectivityManager` by NetworkRequest with [setNetworkSpecifier(xxx)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.Builder#setNetworkSpecifier(java.lang.String)).

Then just pass the network instance as `network` parameter of `Icmp.ping()` method.

```
val icmp = Icmp4a()
val host = "google.com"
val network : android.net.Network = <your network instance>
try {
  val status = icmp.ping(
    host = "8.8.8.8",
    network = network
  )
  val result = status.result
  when (result) {
    is Icmp.PingResult.Success -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) ${result.packetSize} bytes - ${result.ms} ms")
    is Icmp.PingResult.Failed -> Log.d("ICMP", "$host(${status.ip.hostAddress}) Failed: ${result.message}")
  }
} catch (error: Icmp.Error.UnknownHost) {
  Log.d("ICMP", "Unknown host $host")
}
```

Comment: That appears to be your library, you must make that absolutely clear whenever you reference it. [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for letting me know! will fix that